# AngularJS is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I know this might be a repititive question. But I did use all the suggestions and asking this one.

The problem here is: The controller itself is not getting initialized in IE9.

The following is the code for initializing:

```
<body ng-app="MyView" id="appPanel">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="MyController()">
        ...content
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried 
- Using `data-ng-app` as suggested in one of the forums.
- Using other vesions of angular (Current version = 1.3.15).

It works in all the browsers, except IE9 and below. The lower versions is not required. Just the IE9 support should work.

Comment: could you create a plunkr of the same?

Comment: Can you try it with [HTML5Shiv](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv) and comment if it works? HTML5Shiv is created to enable IE9 support.

Comment: Try removing `ng-init="MyController()"`